# Formula is missing an opening or closing parenthesis error message

Tags: excel

When I press ctrl+shft+enter, I get an error message saying "the formula is missing an opening or closing paranethesis". Can you tell me why excel is telling me about missing parenthesis on this formula?

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($A$1:$A$24,MAX(IF(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("[EmailSetMap key=",$A$1:$A$24)),ROW($A$1:$A$24)-ROW($D$1)+1)
```

Comment: _Can you tell me why excel is telling me about missing parenthesis_ well, because you are missing parenthesis...  I count 10 opening and 5 closing

Comment: Ok. Do you know where the closing paranthesis should go? I copied this formula from somewhere else

Comment: Go back to the place on the interweb where you got the formula. You only have half of it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems clear that you're missing a lot of the formula.  You can, if necessary, layout the formula and match up the parentheses manually:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($A$1:$A$24,MAX(IF(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("[EmailSetMap key=",$A$1:$A$24)),ROW($A$1:$A$24)-ROW($D$1)+1)
           |          |     |              |  |  |        |      '------------------------------'|    '----------'    '----'  |
           |          |     |              |  |  |        '--------------------------------------'                            |
           |          |     |              |  |  '----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
           |          |     |              |  '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           |          |     |              '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           |          |     '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           |          '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(Scroll right to see the problem.)  As Jeeped suggested, revisit your source and get the rest.